# Short and sweet riddle

Tags: riddle

One of this and one of that;
Don't you like my fancy hat?
When they looked at what they want,
I was found most elegant.

There's not much of me, you see;
But I'm quite meant to be.
In this social function you'll find:
I'm quite right every time.

Don't hang yourself upon my rhymes,
That will just waste all your time.
But try and find the banquet table:
The dish they're serving is quite fabled.

Hint:

> The fancy hat is a red herring, I just wanted something elegant that rhymed.

Hint #2:

> the hidden tag wasn't statistics, that's a little too ...specific.

Hint #3:

> I guess technically there is a fancy hat, but you have to use your imagination.
>  (Yes, that is a valid hint)

Comment: I am strongly against the usage of a [tag:hidden-tag] tag. IMO, this is a meta tag and will eventually be removed from a question (if it's answered or not answered for a prolonged period). If you mean to hide tags, then please mention so in the body of the question, not in a new tag.

Comment: It was discussed in the meta boards, if you want to continue the discussion, that's the place to do it.

Comment: I agree with @CodeNewbie. 
This tag gives no clue at all, and any answer could be accepted.

Comment: Then it's removed.

Comment: [The answer to the meta discussion](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3334/should-we-hide-tags-or-allow-hidden-tags) has also garnered more downvotes than upvotes, so I would think that this is something the community does not support.

Comment: Sounds like a one-to-one cocktail..

Comment: I'm not familiar with that term. Can you explain?

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer is

> $\hat q$  (as far as I understand it, the estimate of the probability of failure in statistics)

*One of this and one of that;*

> Refers to the practice of sampling in statistics -- take a small sample and base your estimate off of it.

*Don't you like my fancy hat?*

> Refers to the circumflex (hat) on the letter `q`.

*When they looked at what they want,

I was found most elegant.*

> This is the best (most elegant) way of estimating, given a small sample size.

*There's not much of me, you see;*

> It's only a single letter.

*But I'm quite meant to be.*

> `Quite` hints at the letter `q`.

*In this social function you'll find:

I'm quite right every time.*

> Using $\hat q$ to derive an estimate is fairly accurate; another hint at the letter `q`.

*Don't hang yourself upon my rhymes,

That will just waste all your time.*

> Don't take this poem too literally; instead look at all the `q`-words, and derive your answer that way.

*But try and find the banquet table:*

> `Banquet` is another hint at the letter `q`.

*The dish they're serving is quite fabled.*

> $\hat q$ is a well-known variable in statistics.

Comment: From this, I wonder if it might be $\hat{p}$ instead. Generally you want success (p).

Comment: @AggieKidd, feel free to submit your own answer, if you think that's the case.  I picked $\hat q$ because I figured all the `q`-words were hints to the letter `q`.

Comment: Wow, this is really nice. I commend you on your efforts. I'll augment the riddle with some more clarification and some hints.

Answer (score 4):

> π / PI / PIE

One of this and one of that;
 Don't you like my fancy hat?

> π < Hat!

When they looked at what they want,
 I was found most elegant.

> A Raspberry Pi is pretty elegant

There's not much of me, you see;
 But I'm quite meant to be.

> A raspberry pi is small?  Pi is a short word?

In this social function you'll find:
 I'm quite right every time.

> π is a function?

Don't hang yourself upon my rhymes,
 That will just waste all your time.

> Some of this is blah-blah filler stuff?

But try and find the banquet table:
 The dish they're serving is quite fabled.

> Pie!

Comment: How it this not the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Totally ripping off/inspired by GentlePurpleRain's answer:

I think the answer is

> $\hat p$ , the estimated probability of success in statistics.

*One of this and one of that;*

> $\hat{p}$ is often used in binomial trials, which have either success or failure..

*Don't you like my fancy hat?*

> Refers to the circumflex (hat) on the letter `p`, which signifies an estimate.

*When they looked at what they want,

I was found most elegant.*

> Most people are interested in the probability of success *p*, but can't determine that exactly (at least frequentists). Thus, the *hat* makes it possible to estimate, and hats make things more elegant.

*There's not much of me, you see;*

> It's only a single letter, and in many trials the probability for success may be small.

*But I'm quite meant to be.*

> `The probability of something happening - meant to be - is *p*.

*In this social function you'll find:

I'm quite right every time.*

> \hat{p} is the best estimator of the probability of success.

*Don't hang yourself upon my rhymes,

That will just waste all your time.*

> Flipped upside down, a *p* may look like a noose hanging from something.

*But try and find the banquet table:*

> *p* is often confusing in statistics because it is used to denote a lot of different things. Damn statisticians not having much imagination...

*The dish they're serving is quite fabled.*

> *p* for p-values, probability, estimates of probability, etc...

All of this would lead me to guess that the "hidden tag" discussed in comments and in previous edits is:

> Probability

Comment: A lot of your findings are based on some solid logic, which is really nice. The thing you're looking for, however, is more than one letter. I wouldn't be so ambiguous as to say "there's not much of me" instead of "there's only one of me."

Answer (score 2):

My guess:

> AI (Artificial Intelligence)

One of this and one of that; Don't you like my fancy hat?

> One of th**i**s (I) and one of th**a**t (A) = AI

When they looked at what they want, I was found most elegant.

> Humans want AI, and they are elegant.

There's not much of me, you see; But I'm quite meant to be.

> There aren't many AIs so far, but they are inevitable in the near future.

In this social function you'll find: I'm quite right every time.

> Some AIs can perform social functions / chatbots can reply with context to human users.

But try and find the banquet table: The dish they're serving is quite fabled.

> AI has been written about for decades and so is 'fabled'.

Hint #3:

> The A could be seen as a hat with some imagination.

Comment: I'm not quite sure that they are *right* every time in social situations. Usually that's where they seem to go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Are you...

> a royal flush?

One of this and one of that;
Don't you like my fancy hat?

> a royal flush consists of 1 of each of the top cards in poker

When they looked at what they want,
I was found most elegant.

> a royal flush is all high numbers and contains all 3 of the royal cards (Jack, Queen, King)

There's not much of me, you see;
But I'm quite meant to be.

In this social function you'll find:
I'm quite right every time.

> It's very rare to get a royal flush, but getting one will win you the game

Don't hang yourself upon my rhymes,
That will just waste all your time.
But try and find the banquet table:
The dish they're serving is quite fabled.

> Banquet tables could be used for playing poker. The dish could be referring to the rare hand or to winning the jackpot.